# how to shift hamburger strip in codename one

Tags: codenameone

How to shift hamburger  strip in codename name one . here is a sample image [Sample Image for my App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S4ly.jpg)[I want  to put the Hamburger TIME strip in place of My Logo white strip which is on the top in the below image. I have designed it through designer(drag and drop) and not through coding. ][2]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
A mcve can also serve as the foundation for proposing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that:

- Set the padding of the Toolbar on the top to a large enough number (in millimeters) set its background to have an empty border and set the background image to match the design of your logo with an opaque color. You can align the logo to the TOP in the background settings and this will achieve that effect see the [theming section in the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html) for image alignment settings.
- Use `setTitleComponent` on the `Toolbar` and replace the content entirely. You can avoid using `addCommand` to the toolbar and just place the icons wherever you want within the layout. You can hide the side menu icon which is added automatically by using a [theme constant](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html).